# how to use LIKE n1ql query in couchbase?

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase, sql++

I am want to represent a matter that i haven't understand yet . I show you a following example .
This is my documents

```
doc 1 : {"type":"81"}
doc 2 : {"type":"81_"}
doc 3 : {"type":"8"}
doc 4 : {"type":"8_"}
doc 5 : {"type":"13"}
```

And now, I want to query using n1ql to fetch documents that match **type like "8_%"** 8_ should be a String prefix

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where code like "8_%" ") 
**or**
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where code like (concat(8,_,'%')) ")
```

Both of them not correct anwser that i am except.Response should only have one doc is **doc 4 
: {"type":"8_"}** . But this response following documents .

```
 doc 1 : {"type":"81"}
 doc 2 : {"type":"81_"}
 doc 3 : {"type":"8"}
 doc 4 : {"type":"8_"}
```

Can you help me in situation ? Thank you in advanced .I am using **Couchbase 3.1.8** . Sorry my bad english

Answer (score 1):

The following query should return right results

```
SELECT META().id FROM mybucket WHERE type LIKE "8_%"
```

Match string with a wildcard expression. Use % for zero or more wildcards and _ to match any character at this place in a string ( https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/comparisonops.html)

If you want match _ as it is escape it.

```
SELECT META().id FROM mybucket WHERE type LIKE "8\\_%";
```

If you are using Couchbase 3.1.8, it is very old and you should try latest Couchbase version 6.5.0.

I think the N1QL release is started in Couchbase 4.0.0

Comment: not change , repsonse still return four above document although i have updated CB up 6.5.0

Comment: It look like you want match _ as it is. Updated response try again

Comment: wow , character \\ really working well ,  response has had correctly . Thank you so much